# Ordinal multinomial logistic regression on one-hot encoded data

Tags: r, logistic, multicollinearity, computational-statistics, categorical-encoding

I have a task I am unable to tackle by principle. I'm working on survey data for one of our clients such that my design matrix is made of one-hot vectors with 15 features (originally 3 variables with 5 categorical classes).

I want to evaluate the importance of every feature in predicting a discrete outcome (the net promoter score going from 1-10).

What I already know is that one-hot encoded data has perfect co-linearity, meaning that using the design matrix as is will yield unstable and meaningless results.

What I already tried is using a linear model with penalization such as Lasso and Ridge. The results were catastrophic with p-values hitting 99%.

I wish to tackle the problem from a logistic regression approach in hopes of getting more significant results but I have no idea how to implement it. The functions I already used such as *polr* and the *DisplayR* package assume low multicolinearity, is there a penalized logistic approach? Or a way to process my data?

Comment: OK, A) You shouldn't be computing p values from a penalized model. B) You should be specifying a hypothesis *and then seeing if there is evidence for an effect* rather than hoping you "[get] more significant results".  If you have perfect collinearity, maybe you should exclude one of the features.  Instead of using polr (which IIRC can be pretty picky with how the design matrix should be passed) you could try using brms' implementation of a continuing logit model.

Comment: Are you saying p-values are irrelevant for penalized models? I have seen several articles and libraries that compute p-values for Ridge and Lasso and I assumed accordingly they would be significant to some extent.

Comment: The penalization removes the asymptotic unbiased interpretation of the coefficients.  Rob Tibshirani recently (2015) published a paper which attempts to provide confidence intervals for penalized models, and so if that is what you are referring to then that is fine.

Comment: @DemetriPananos 
"If you have perfect collinearity, maybe you should exclude one of the features"
I have seen many resources do that, and it does kinda work, but none of them tries to infer importance from the coefficients, or indicates how to extract the importance of the feature that was extracted. Linear approaches supposes the intercept carries information about the dummy variable coefficient but I fail to see how this translates to logistic multinomial ordered regression. In any case thank you for your insights.